# Sum values of same name in foreach loop php

Tags: php, foreach

How to SUM same value in forech if i have output like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 200,2,
    [1] => 200,3,
    [2] => 300,5,
)
```

Output should be like

```
'200' => 5,
'300' => 5,
```

So group name `200` and SUM value so result is 2+3

```
$ga->requestReportData(
        ga_profile_id,
        array('date','pagePath'),
        array('pageviews'),
        '-pageviews',
        'ga:pagePathLevel1==/post/ && ga:pagePathLevel2=~^\/[0-9]+\/$',
        $date,
        $date,
    1);
    foreach ($ga->getResults() as $result) {
        $pageviews = $result->getPageviews();
        $pagepath = $result->getPagePath();
        if(is_numeric(get_part_url($pagepath))){
            print 'INSERT INTO stats (views,content_id) VALUES ("'.$pageviews.'","'.get_part_url($pagepath).'")';
        }
    }
```

`get_part_url` is just function to extract part of url.

Comment: what generates this output (it's nothing in the code you showed here)

Comment: Edited question

Comment: I can only repeat my first comment.... and add: what is `$ga`? what is the method `requestReportData()` doing? Is that some framework you didn't mention?

Comment: Yes it's a Google analytics api

Comment: `$arr = ['200' => 2, '500' => 5, '200' => 3];` Will not work, you cannot have the same **index** point twice in an array.. This will output as `Array ( [200] => 3 [500] => 5 )`... Please provide us with an exported version of the **real** data

Comment: Here is `print_r($result)` https://pastebin.com/49qrbRJ4, also i have using `get_part_url` function to extract only part of url in this example part of url is 111.. so you can see this url two times in this output... i need to group them and sum pageviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new array to group all your results into. Note you may receive notices about offsets, just check firstly the key `isset()` to stop this or use `error_reporting(E_ERROR);` to not show warnings.

```
$groupedResults = array();

foreach ($ga->getResults() as $result) {
    $pageviews = $result->getPageviews();
    $pagepath = get_part_url($result->getPagePath());
    if(is_numeric($pagepath)) $groupedResults[$pagepath] += $pageviews;
}
```

You can then loop through these and run your DB queries.

```
foreach ($groupedResults as $k => $v) {
     print 'INSERT INTO stats (views,content_id) VALUES ("'.$v.'","'.$k.'")';
}
```

See a [working example here](https://3v4l.org/u8nf8) with example data.

Comment: I think this is exactly what i need

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array and sum the value.

```
$newArray=array();
Foreach( $myarray as             $key=>$value)
{
   If(!isset($newArray[$key])
  {
     $newArray[$key]=$value;
  }
  Else
  {
     $newArray+=$value;
  }
```

Comment: true, but: do you know what `$myarray` would be in the question?